# RegionUnion for 3D Regions

Tags: regions, computational-geometry

I make two regions and then find I can't combine them using `RegionUnion`. Here are the two regions.

```
r1 = Region@RegionDifference[
    RegionDifference[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {20, 0, 0}}, 6], 
     Cuboid[{0, 5, -6}, {20, 6, 6}]],
    Cuboid[{0, -6, -6}, {20, -5, 6}]
    ];
r2 = Region[Cylinder[{{20, 0, 0}, {28.5, 0, 0}}, 1/2]];
{r1, r2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I check their dimensions and plot them using `Show`.

```
    Show[r1, r2, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 Boxed -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So far so good. Now I attempt to combine them using `RegionUnion` and then plot them over the same dimensions as I used in the `Show`

```
r3 = RegionUnion[r1, r2];
Region[r3, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Boxed -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All I have is a cuboid at one end of my plot.

What's  going wrong? Version 11.3

**Edit**

@N.J.Evans suggested I try a simpler region. It did't work for him in Version 11.2.

```
r0 = Region[Cuboid[{15, -5, -5}, {20, 5, 5}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[r0, r2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
r4 = RegionUnion[r0, r2];
Region[r4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So that worked in Version 11.3. Looks like we have different problems in different versions.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to work with discretized regions in your application? If so, look into `DiscretizeRegion`.

Comment: @Hugh, that's better than what I got! I'm on 11.2 and I ran your code and got several errors when execution made it to `r3`, and then my CPU started working real hard and I had to kill the kernel. Maybe some kind of bug? I reduced it to the union of a cylinder and a cuboid and it still went crazy.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks, but is there an easy way to join several regions after they have been discritised?  Must I make one region and then discritise?

Comment: @N.J.Evans Looking at a simpler union is a good idea. I will try.

Comment: @Hugh I think `Region` function is meant for visualization purposes and you can drop it from inside `RegionUnion` and friends.

Comment: @Pinti Thank you for that observation. You are correct. Although `RegionUnion` states that the components must be a region it is not clear what is regarded as a region. The head does not have to be region. Is there a list of items that are considered to be regions?

Comment: @Hugh You can test that with `RegionQ` or `BoundedRegionQ`. The latter is probably more appropriate if you want to discretize that region.

Answer (score 5):

Note that this is only an issue with the display -- the region itself is still correct. We can see this by sampling a bunch of random points:

```
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Tiny], 
  Point[RandomPoint[r3, 100000, {{0, 30}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

As a workaround, you can discretize then perform boolean operations:

```
r1 = Fold[RegionDifference, BoundaryDiscretizeRegion /@ {Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {20, 0, 0}}, 6], 
  Cuboid[{0, 5, -6}, {20, 6, 6}], Cuboid[{0, -6, -6}, {20, -5, 6}]}];

r2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cylinder[{{20, 0, 0}, {28.5, 0, 0}}, 1/2]];

r3 = RegionUnion[r1, r2]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works well. Thank you. Clearly a plotting problem and working with `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` gives a workaround.